# Crash on UDT with string and another UDT between VBA and C++

Tags: c++, excel, vba

I have a problem between the VBA and the C++.
When I want to redim my X array, it's crash with my release dll. 
If I compile in debug, it's work sometimes but when I look my X array, I have an error "application-defined or object-defined error".

If I don't redim the X array or if I remove the s string, it's work well.

VBA:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Cpp_D2 Lib "MyDLL.dll" (i As T) As Long

Private Type XData
    X() As Double
    Count As Long
End Type

Private Type T
    s As String
    data_T As XData
End Type

Sub Test()
    Dim i As T
    ReDim i.data_T.X(5)
    i.s = "ok"
    Call Cpp_D2(i)
End Sub
```

C++:

```
__declspec(align(4)) typedef struct XData
{
    LPSAFEARRAY X;
    int Count;
}   XData;

__declspec(align(4)) typedef struct T
{
    BSTR s;
    XData X;
} T;

__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall  Cpp_D2(T *p)
{
    double *x = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(p->X.X, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&x));
    SafeArrayUnaccessData(p->X.X);
    return 0;
}
```

I use an 32 bit version of Excel and Visual Studio 2010 to compile the c++ dll.

On Mac, I have one message before the crash: "Internal error (Error 51)" The information on the official documentation about this error is:

"An internal malfunction has occurred in Visual Basic. Unless this call was generated by the Error statement or Raise method, contact Microsoft Product Support Services to report the conditions under which the message appeared."

I used this example to do the job: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/171583 and this example works fine.

Comment: Shouldn't `Dim obj As T` be `Dim i As T` ?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I edited, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the memory is corrupted but I found a workaround. 
We don't need to change anything in C++. On VBA, the aim is to pass the address of the User Defined Type ByVal like this:

```
Call Cpp_D2(VarPtr(i))
```

And, it's important to change the declaration of the C++ function like this:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Cpp_D2 Lib "MyDLL.dll" (ByVal i As Long) As Long
```

Now, it's work when I have the both declaration in C++ and VBA of the User Defined Type without MIDL.